# W3C CSS Validator result 'Value Error : font-family Property font-family doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in [css1, css2, css3] : Helvetica'

Tags: css, font-face, w3c-validation

I am getting two errors in w3 css validtor as

1. Value Error : font-family Property font-family doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but exists in [css1, css2, css3] : Helvetica
2. Property src doesn't exist : url('tl_files/Helvetica.ttf') format("truetype" )

my css with these code is\

```
@font-face{font-family:Helvetica;src: url('tl_files/Helvetica.ttf') format("truetype");}
```

how can I rectify these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange-looking error, but just switch your validation profile to CSS level 3 and that will sort it. You can find this in a drop-down menu on the page where you entered your code to validate.

Answer (score 1):

its a css3 property, and you should select css level 3 in the validation process