# CSS font-variant of @font-face deprecated?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

When I paste `@font-face` - `font-variant` [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-variant#setting_the_small-caps_font_variant) to [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input), it gives me error that:

> font-variant doesn't exist in CSS Level 3 + SVG but exists in [css1, css2, css21, css3] : small-caps

I haven't found any information on the MDN or anywhere else, that `font-variant` is being removed from standard. I'm confused by this. Can I or should I not use `font-variant` in `@font-face`? If not, are there any other `@font-face` properties [listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) that should not be used in `@font-face` (other than those not yet fully supported)?

Comment: I don't see any such wording in your links. Perhaps it is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205267/w3c-css-validator-result-value-error-font-family-property-font-family-doesnt

Comment: You have to take the MDN example and paste it in CSS validator. I've looked at your link. It seems to me like CSS validator problem because if i keep profile `CSS Level 3 + SVG` it says that it exists in specifications `[css1, css2, css21, css3]` so I switched to specification `CSS level 3` and now it says that it exists only in specifications `[css1, css2, css21]`.

Comment: The real think that I wanted to verify is if I can write something like this:
`@font-face {
font-family: ... ;
src: ...;
font-variant-caps: small-caps all-small-caps;
}`
I.e. defining that the imported font file supports multiple values for same `font-variant` subproperty.